# Mongo DB Map Reduce skipping records

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to skip records from mongo map reduce utility using the below command.

```
 db.<collectionName>.mapReduce(
 "function () { counter++; if (counter > <numberOfRecordsToBeSkipped>){ emit(this.fieldName, 1); } }",
 "function (key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }" ,
 {"out" : <CollectionName>,"scope" : "{var counter:0}" , 
 "limit" : 0}
 );
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
     "errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: counter is not defined nofile_b:0",
        "code" : 9014,
"ok" : 0
}
```

Could anyone please help me on that? I understand that scope attribute can be used to define global variables to be used in map/reduce functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the syntax you have is wrong for the `scope` parameter:

```
scope: { counter: 0 }
```

You'll also encounter the problem that the `scope` document is intended to be read-only. It would not work in a sharded setup if the document passed to `scope` were to change only on one shard server. Further, there's no guarantee that the order of documents processed by a map-reduce will be the same from execution to execution. So, it would produce inconsistent results.

Here's a simple test with a document that has a `userid` field:

```
{
     userid: 1234 
}
```

Code:

```
map = function () { counter++; if (counter > 1){ emit(this.userid, 1); } }
reduce = function (key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }
```

In use:

```
db.tw.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "tw2", scope: { counter: 0 } })
```

The code executes as expected. By presetting `counter` to a value, I controlled how many documents were processed in the `map` phase. I confirmed the output matched expectations.

If I change the map code:

```
map = function () { counter++; if (counter > numberToSkip) { emit(this.userid, 1); } }
```

And try to call the `mapReduce` function without any changes, I'll see an `errmsg` with:

```
ReferenceError: numberToSkip is not defined near 'ounter > numberToSkip){ emit(thi' "
```

Comment: Thank you. However I tried what you suggested as well, but still getting the same issue. Somehow the variable I define in scope is not available for the map function.

Comment: Do you have another error somewhere? I can get it to work. And it's not even read-only yet (MongoDB has suggested they were going to make scope variables read-only). Your code has other JavaScript errors.

Comment: Also - what version of MongoDB are you using? It's a bit strange that the error you're seeing doesn't match what I see.

Comment: Thank you. I dont have any other error other than the reference error I mentioned in my question. I am using Mongo 2.2.7. Let me try again with functions defined like how you have done instead of doing inline map/reduce functions.

Comment: When I tried defining functions first and then use those functions in my map reduce command instead of inline functions, it works! Don't know why. Thank you for the help.